# AngularJS Replace Text of Menubar as user navigates

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

This is Angular 1.5 app. I have written the Menu bar in index.html file to keep it common in all views. Right now, Menu bar default value is set to home screen - "Personal". Other webpages' names aren't present in menu bar, instead an icon is present to represent those pages in menu bar. 
When the user navigates to any other page, the name of that particular page should get displayed in menu bar and rest pages should be displayed as icon in menu bar.

How do I achieve this 
This is how the menu looks like currently-
[image: This is how the menu looks like]

Here is my `<body>` of index.html file.

```
    <body>
        <div class="page" id="page">
            <ul id="progress">
                <li class="active progress-li">
                  Personal 
                </li> 
                <li class="progress-li"> 
                  <a ng-href="#/school">
                    <i class="fa fa-building-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li class="progress-li">
                  <a ng-href="#/pre-university">
                    <i class="fa fa-university" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li class="progress-li">
                  <a ng-href="#/university">
                    <i class="fa fa-graduation-cap" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li class="progress-li">
                  <a ng-href="#/extras">
                    <i class="fa fa-cubes" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li class="progress-li">
                  <a ng-href="#/accolades">
                    <i class="fa fa-trophy" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li class="progress-li-last">
                  <a ng-href="#/job">
                    <i class="fa fa-suitcase" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <main class="cf" ng-view></main>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/libs/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/libs/angular/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/libs/angular/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/libs/angular/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>  
</body>
```